# How does NetBeans deals with IntelliJ annotations?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ to write my code in Java. Sometimes of course I'm forced to use some MySQL. Usually the query is a simple String object, but IDE allows to inject language to make the query more readable. I can inject MySQL syntax temporary, but after restarting IntelliJ query is a simple String again. To make it permanent in code, you have to type:

```
@Language("MySQL") String query = "SELECT * FROM table";
```

It's ok when everybody working on the project use the same IDE, but e.g. our PM uses NetBeans. Will it still compile in his IDE if I use this kind of annotation? Can NetBeans handle these?

Comment: I think IDE have no annotations. If it have own annotations, it's some kind of weird behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Language annotation is provided by IntelliJ, it's included in a .jar archive. You have to add this archive to your NetBeans project, otherwise your code won't be compiled. By adding the dependency, the code will compile, but I think with no functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether those annotations are performing something using annotation processor. NetBeans supports annotation processors directly in the same wasy as IntelliJ. So it should always work.

The project will be compilable in NetBeans if you will provide those annotations on compile classpath.

Answer (score 0):

As an annotation changes the dependencies, in principle to be avoided.

[@Language](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/general-usage.html) defined in IntelliJ plugin **annotations.jar**. But probably usable as no-op in NetBeans.

As it seems not feasible to emulate this feature, one still might write a tool to extract SQL strings.

This means there is some justification, if you take this effort and explain this IntelliJ feature. Otherwise I would refrain from using this annotation.